# Duda implementación relación 1 a 1 en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy empezando un proyecto en laravel, en el que los usuarios tienen dos tipos de roles (profesional y paciente), para ello en la plataforma tengo un único formulario de registro y según seleccionen una selección u otra de un checkbox se registra con un rol u otro.
En el controlador Register tengo esto:

```
    protected function create(array $data){
      
  if ($data['type_user'] == 'paciente') {

            $patient = new Patient();
            $patient->save();
        } else {
            $profesional = new Professional();
            $profesional->professional_number = $data['num_col'];
            $profesional->save();
        }




        return User::create([

            'name' => $data['name'],
            'last_name1' => $data['last_name1'],
            'last_name2' => $data['last_name2'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            // por defecto es activo=>1
            'user_status_id' => 1,
            'rgpd' => $data['rgpd'],
            'ads' => $data['ads']  ?? 0,
            'patients_id' => $patient->id??null,
            'professional_id' => $profesional->id??null,

        ]);
    }
```

¿Sería correcta esta implementación o habría otra forma de hacerlo?

Gracias

Comment: creo que seria mas optimo crear una tabla de roles, imagina que mañana se cree un nuevo rol llamado practicante, deberías modificar tu código y eso no es bueno

Comment: Como dice Nicolas lo mejor es crear una tabla de roles y si los usuarios solo pueden tener un tipo de rol entonces puedes agregar lo como campo a la tabla usuarios role_id por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta *podría* considerarse basada en opiniones, dado que hay muchas maneras de solucionar tu caso de uso.

Sin embargo, pienso que hay una sola manera elegante  y es justamente la que sugiere la documentación para manejar en una sola relación la pertenencia lógica de un modelo a más de un posible tipo. Esta relación [Polimórfica](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations) se plantearía diciendo que el usuario tiene un perfil, y que el objeto de ese perfil es un registro de paciente o profesional. Podemos decir que esos dos modelos son "*perfilables*",

---

##### MorphOne

Si cada usuario tiene **un** solo perfil posible, entonces podrías implementarlo diciendo que el usuario tiene relación con un perfilable usando, en vez de

```
  User
    id
    name
    email
    ...
    patients_id
    professional_id
```

las propiedades `perfilable_id` y `perfilable_type`.

```
  User
    id
    name
    email
    ...
    perfilable_id
    perfilable_type
```

Donde `perfilable_id` sería la llave única en el modelo perfilable, y `perfilable_type` sería `App\Models\Patient` o `App\Models\Professional`.

En la declaración de modelos, tu usuario tendría:

```
 public function perfilable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
 }
```

Esa convención le dice, a partir del nombre de la relación, que busque dos campos que coincidan con éste y los sufijos `_id` y `_type`.

En los modelos Patient y Professional declararías la relación inversa para obtener qué usuario es el que ostenta ese perfil:

```
 public function user() {
    return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'perfilable');
 }
```

Es más, podrías declarar la relación que hoy tienen ambos perfilables en un trait:

```
trait Perfilable {
     public function user() {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'perfilable');
     }
}
```

Y en tus modelos perfilables de hoy, mañana y siempre, usar el trait

class xxxx extends Model {

```
    use Perfilable;
    ...
```

}

Puedes usar otro término en vez de `perfilable` cuidando de sustituir en los métodos y atributos.

Al crear tu usuario le dirías qué modelo perfilable le estás asignando, junto con el id:

```
 $user = User::create([...]);

if($data['type_user']) {
    $perfilable = new Patient();
    $perfilable_type = Patient::class;
} else {
    $perfilable = Professional::create([$num_col => $data['num_col']]);
    $perfilable_type = Professional::class;
}
$perfilable->save();

$user->perfilable_id = $perfilable->id;
$user->perfilable_type = $perfilable_type;
```

Aunque en realidad no necesitas definir `$perfilable_type` porque puedes poner

```
$user->perfilable_type = get_class($perfilable);
```

Con eso puedes obtener la entidad usando `$user->perfilable` sin detenerte a ver cuál de los dos campos es no nulo. Pero si necesitas hacerlo siempre podrás usar `$user->perfilable_type` como discriminante.

Esto funcionará transparentemente si el día de mañana añades otros modelos perfilables simplemente poniendo que usan el Trait.

---

#### MorphToMany

Si tus usuarios pueden ostentar más de un perfil, entonces será necesario tener una tabla intermedia que haga esas asociaciones, puesto que no podrías guardar más de un perfilable en un mismo registro de usuario.

El enfoque polimórfico para hacer esto se hace con el tipo de relación [MorphToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations), y explicarlo acá sólo contribuiría a confundir.